# PHP .htaccess redirect to a folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have PHP .htaccess to manage user profile like this :

```
http://example.com/user?=blabla
```

to be

```
http://example.com/blabla
```

Here is the .htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ post.php?user=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/home/.*$ index.php [QSA]
```

Now I want to make like this :

```
http://example.com/blabla/post/
```

post is a folder.

I tried make folder post in root folder but still wrong. But when I tried to type this URL, http://example.com/user/post it running OK.

What I want is user can open `http://example.com/blabla/post/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+?)/?$ $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The error is : Object not found! I just have 1 rule in .htaccess. blabla is not a directory, but it get from user.php?user=$1. post is a directory. Assuming like twitter : https://twitter.com/davidalwis/status/537153967289954304

Comment: Tried and get result : Server error! The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request...

Comment: Are there more rules or only this rule in .htaccess. If there is more then post your full .htaccess here.

Comment: Hi... Please see my updated post above for .htaccess

Comment: `Object not found!` comes from the PHP page ?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is from .htaccess, when will redirect to folder post.

Comment: No, I think anubhava rule work well, You have to adapt your PHP program to new data

Comment: @user2571904: Your .htaccess was full of bugs. I am posting your complete .htaccess in my answer, try it and let me know.